# Express cannot find module

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack, passport.js

I'm trying to create a login using Passport in a MEAN stack.
I'm now loading up all the modules required to setup Passport but it stops working on one line of code. I use Express as a framework.

When I start the server it gives me the following error:

> Error: Cannot find module './models/user'

This is my app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/homeapp');

var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(require('express-session')({
  secret: 'designer cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
var User = require('./models/user');
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Folder Structure:

```
├── app.js
├── bin
│   └── www
├── package.json
├── models
│   └── Users.js
├── node_modules
├── public
│   ├── images
│   ├── javascripts
│   └── stylesheets
│       └── style.css
├── routes
│   ├── index.js
│   └── users.js
└── views
    ├── error.jade
    ├── index.jade
    └── layout.jade
```

Comment: Can you also show me the folder structure? Is there user.js in models directory?

Comment: I've added the folder structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `var User = require('./models/user');` to `var User = require('./models/User');`

Your folder structure shows the user model as Uppercase.

Comment: Awesome it works ! However the image size increased too much, from 180MB, I have an image of 720MB :O :O.